# Trying to iterate through a column to populate another column

Tags: pandas, dictionary, append, iteration

I am trying to populate the column num_crimes. Since the zipcode repeats in the houses data frame, I just want to add the number of crimes related to that zipcode from the dictionary containing all the crimes per zipcode.

the houses dataframe contains 5000 entries, and the dictionary contains only 67, so I cannot just merge them.

This is the houses dataframe:

```
sold_price | zipcode | fireplaces | num_crimes
 5300000   |  85637  |      6     | NaN
 4200000   |  85646  |      5     | NaN
 4200000   |  85646  |      5     | NaN
 4500000   |  85646  |      6     | NaN
 3411450   |  85750  |      4     | NaN
```

and this is the dictionary:

```
{85141: 1,85601: 2, 85607: 1, 85614: 4, 85622: 2, 85629: 4, 85634: 1....}
```

**Problem:** this is the code I used for that, but it is not changing the values in num_crimes:

```
def populate(df1):

for row, rows in df1.iterrows():
    
    if rows[1] in my_dict:
        rows[3]=my_dict[rows[1]]
    else:
        rows[3]=0
```

Comment: it won't the `rows` object is a copy not a reference .object.  simpler approach would be to load your dict into a dataframe and do a `merge`.  Paste your data as text not images

Comment: I fixed the data problem.
I cannot just merge, because the houses dataframe is 5 thousand data points and my dictionary has only 67 data points.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do something like:

```
df["num_crimes"] = df["zipcode"].apply(lambda z: my_dict[z])
```

If you have zipcode in df that are not in my_dict, you need to handle for that as well:

```
df["num_crimes"] = df["zipcode"].apply(lambda z: my_dict[z] if z in my_dict else -1)
```

Comment: it gave me back an error that was the value for the zip code, no explanation

Comment: That probably means you have zipcode in your df that does not exist in the df. You can add an error handling in the code above to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to answer your questions if you post your data as text rather than images. Anyways, you could make the dict into a dataframe and then join it with the original dataframe. So something like this:

```
houses.set_index("Zipcode").join(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index', columns = ["Crimes from dict"]))
```

Would that work?

Comment: I fixed the data problem. I cannot just merge, because the houses dataframe is 5 thousand data points and my dictionary has only 67 data points

Comment: You don't merge, you join it. So it doesn't matter if you have 5k datapoints in the df and 67 data points in the dict,since they will map on the keys. This is a minimum example: data = {'Zipcode': [1, 2, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.set_index("Zipcode").join(pd.DataFrame.from_dict({1:4}, orient='index', columns = ["Crimes"])).

See how the rows with Zipcode 1 all have 4 in the "Crime"-column?

Comment: Thank you,
it deleted the zipcode column but I can just merge that back.

Comment: I would highly appreciate if you could be kind enough to explain that syntax step by step.  it is working, but I don't understand it.
Thank you so far my kind sir.